# What is the execution order in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-material

I am a newbie starting to use angular-material. I am working with a side bar.

Basically, it was like

```
<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
</md-sidenav>
<md-button id="side-button" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></md-button>
```

```js
$scope.toggleLeft = function() {
                $mdSidenav('left').toggle()
                    .then(function(){
                        $log.debug("toggle left is done");
                    });
            };
```

It worked as expected. But there is a peculiar thing that when I wrote after that js another line:

```
timeLine.toggle_left_most = $scope.toggleLeft();
```

And replaced the `ng-click="toggleLeft()"` with `ng-click="timeLine.toggle_left_most()"`, it returned with me "No instance found for handle 'left'".

But when I inserted a line behind `$mdSidenav('left').toggle()` to query the element with md-component-id="left", it returned that object. This leads me to ask about the execution order and deeper principles of AngularJS.

My question is that, why does it return "No instance found" when DOM are already loaded? Why does adding one line of assignment breaks the code? Does $mdSidenav requires not only the DOM but also some other things loaded? What is that crucial thing?

Is the problem because of that when I don't write that line, the assignment to $scope.toggleLeft won't be immediately executed? Then when is it executed?

Comment: directives has `priority: 0,` attribute you can set it

Answer (score 2):

You declared

```
timeLine.toggle_left_most = $scope.toggleLeft();
```

but `timeLine` object will not be available to your html template since it is not a $scope variable so your code should be as follows

```
var toggleLeft=function() {
                $mdSidenav('left').toggle()
                    .then(function(){
                        $log.debug("toggle left is done");
                    });
            };

$scope.timeLine.toggle_left_most=toggleLeft;
```

usually i am following above style.
I am not sure this the answer...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions are Objects. If you use `()` you are executing the function, but it is important to understand that you are not managing function's definition.

So, `timeLine.toggle_left_most = $scope.toggleLeft();`
Is actually running `$scope.toggleLeft` and assigning its returned value to `timeLine.toggle_left_most`.

I don't understand why would you want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `No instance found for handle left` is described here - https://github.com/SebastianMetzger/angular-material-inbox/issues/1

Besides the solution described there, this worked out for me - using `getInstances` method of $mdComponentRegistry to check what items are available at the moment and skipping is there's none:

```
//on some event, state change for example
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toStateParams) {
  if ($mdComponentRegistry.getInstances().length) $mdSidenav('left').close();
});
```